# Cucumber JS step definition timeout not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver, cucumber, cucumberjs

My step times out always at 15ms even though I have set the limit to be 30ms.

Here's the code:

```
this.Then(/^The "(.*)" page is displayed$/, {timeout: 30 * 1000}, async    (name) => {
    let result;
    switch (name.toLowerCase()) {
      case 'home':
        result = await confirmation.isDisplayed();
        break;
      default:
        throw Error('Please specify a valid page name: ' + name);
    }
    expect(result).to.equal(true);
  });
```

The confirmation page takes over 15 seconds to load due to payment being processed.

The test fails all the time with a timeout of 15 seconds. The payment process takes over 20 seconds. I've set the timeout limit to 30 seconds but it still times out at 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

When I have these kinds of feature questions, my first step is to search the cucumber-js spec section and look at how the tests use the feature, in this case timeout.  [This](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/1e8a271bce03670374b10a7e229b6e91a2ff763d/features/step_definition_timeouts.feature) looks interesting.  You can search the cucumber-js [repo](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js) for timeout.  Look especially under the spec folder.